# Scheduling a SAS job in UNIX (via PuTTY)

Tags: shell, sas, tcsh

I want to schedule a SAS job in UNIX (via PuTTY). I used AT command for scheduling purposes. I use SASB command usually to add a SAS job to the queue. I used the following command to schedule:

```
at now 
at nice nohup sasb < test.sas > & output &
```

and then `Control + d` to save the schedule. I am getting the error:

> stty: : Inappropriate ioctl for device

Please let me know what is wrong how can I fix this.

```
SHELL - TCSH
OSTYPE - SOLARIS
```

Comment: That looks like errors I have seen from users that have unconditionally executed `stty` commands in their startup files. When you run a batch job there is no terminal so the stty command gives an error message.  Doesn't really have anything to do with SAS unless the stty command is in your sasb script.

Comment: Please someone let me know the answer to the above question .The issue still persists and I am unable find a solution to the above problem .If the issue stated above is not vivid please let me know ?I will try to frame it with more description .

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Crontab](https://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) for scheduling  instead, your command should look similar to my example below:

```
/sas/940/SASFoundation/9.4/sas /projects/program1.sas -log "/projects/program1.log"
```

SAS Command line documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation//cdl/en/hostunx/67929/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0a9pg9dddvvbkn1rll5kefgvr2q.htm)